# Apply for a new China visa

Tags: visas, china

I am currently studying in Beijing for a summer Program of 1 month. I have been given à X2 Study visa of 60 days even if my courses only last 30 days but only have 1 entry. As my courses are going to finish and I still can stay 1 month in China according to my visa I would like to travel to Thaïland for 10 days and then come back to China. However as I only have one entry visa my visa will be cancelled.

Could I apply for a new visa, a tourism one this time when I will be in Thaïland or you think it is not possible to ask for a new visa when you had previously another one ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know about China specifically, but some countries require you to apply for visas from your country of residence. I'm not sure why you think that having had one visa would disqualify you from having another one in the future. It's completely normal to travel to a country more than once.

Answer (score 1):

China requires you do apply for a visa from your country of residence unless you apply at the airport for a temporary visa and are allowed to do so according to those rules.

Just beware that the rules for applying for visa at the arrival airport in China is fairly new and the rules changes frequently so it can be an adventure to do so, as part of my job I run a service that helps people traveling in China so we have a fair bit of experience and comments surrounding this and the results are very varied.

To be safe make sure you have the proper valid visa before arriving in China and if you need apply for one do so from your home country